# SQL alter script - copying from one table to another

Tags: sql, oracle, copy

I'm trying to figure out how to implement the alter script described below.  I'm familiar with the basics if insert/select already, but this is a lot more complex.

I have a legacy table and need to move its data to a new table with more columns.  The new table has already been made public to some select users, who may have already manually moved the common data over.

So for each row in LegacyTable:

- see if it already exists in NewImprovedTable (by checking for a match on a string field that exists in both tables)
- if not, copy its over to NewImprovedTable
- regardless of whether it had been copied to NewImprovedTable automatically just now, or previously by the user...

  - auto-populate a new Name field in NewImprovedTable (must be unique - e.g. "Legacy1", "Legacy2", etc.)
  - set an IsLegacy flag in NewImprovedTable

I need to implement this in both MS SQL and Oracle, but once I work out the logic on one I can figure out the syntax on the other.

Comment: Sounds to me like the MERGE statement is the way to go for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I settled on (in SQL Server - still need to port to Oracle):

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
      FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'NewImprovedTable'
      AND COLUMN_NAME = 'legacyFlg')
BEGIN

   ALTER TABLE [NewImprovedTable]
   ADD legacyFlg TINYINT NULL

   ALTER TABLE [LegacyTable]
   ADD improvedId INT NULL
END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ImprovedTable WHERE legacyFlg = 1)
BEGIN

   MERGE ImprovedTable AS TARGET
   USING LegacyTable AS SOURCE
   ON (TARGET.stringField = SOURCE.stringField)
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
         INSERT (name, <other columns>, legacyFlg)
         VALUES('Legacy' + SOURCE.stringField, <other column values>, 1)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
         UPDATE SET TARGET.legacyFlg = 1;

END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM LegacyTable WHERE improvedId <> 0)
BEGIN

   MERGE LegacyTable AS TARGET
   USING NewImprovedTable AS SOURCE
   ON (SOURCE.stringField = TARGET.stringField)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
         UPDATE SET TARGET.improvedId = SOURCE.pId;

END
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using this, where 'input' is the string you are trying to confirm if already exists:

```
SELECT * FROM`NewImprovedTable` WHERE `Variable`='input'
```

This will return the whole row if found any match, if not it will return null, you can play with that

As for the unique ID field you need to create a primary key on your table with the auto increment option enable, for example

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    P_Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
)
```

In this last example P_Id is set as an autoincrement variable, each time you crate a new row it will auto fill this column with a unique number.
You should check this page

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

Comment: You're obviously used to MySQL. Some of this syntax is invalid in Oracle, for example the back ticks and the auto increment. You also shouldn't be using the datatype varchar as how the datatype works is subject to change in future releases.

Comment: ID field is already set up as a primary key/identity, so you're right, it would auto-increment either way.  I'll edit my original post to clarify.  I still need to save that ID back to LegacyTable, but I suppose that could be handled in a second operation, after the data from LegacyTable is copied to NewImprovedTable.